# F# pointer member accessor

Tags: c#, .net, f#, interop, pinvoke

Is there any way of accessing the members of a `NativePtr` struct and assigning a value to them, much in the same way that you can in C# in the below example?

(From MSDN)

`CoOrds* p = &home; 
p -> x = 25;`

Currently I'm making use of `NativePtr.write`, however I'm unsure whether this is the best/correct solution.

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify - you have a `NativePtr<some struct>` and you want to set the named elements of this `struct`?  Do you have an example of how you are currently using `NativePtr.write` to achieve this in F#?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I have made a function which takes the value I wish to update, the NativePtr and the dereferenced struct from that pointer:

`NativePtr.write ptr p`.

Prior to calling `NativePtr.write`, I have updated a member within the `p` struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you described is the clearest way of doing this, presuming that you must deal with the `struct`s in this manner.  For completeness' sake, here's that method (with the implementation details of the packing omitted):

```
open FSharp.NativeInterop

[<StructLayout(...)>]
type myStructure =
    struct
        val mutable a : int
        val mutable b : byte
    end

let changeA pointer newA =
    let mutable structure = NativePtr.read pointer
    structure.a <- newA
    NativePtr.write pointer structure
```

However, because you must know the exact offsets of each of the elements, you could also use this information to write directly to that field.  F# does not provide a way of doing this using named identifiers, and its strict typing of the `nativeptr<'T>` type means that you cannot simply cast to the relevant pointer type.  The `NativePtr.set offset ptr` function adds `sizeof<'T> * offset`, so this is also no use in this case.

Let's say the type `myStructure` has the `Packed` attribute, for simplicity.  The offsets are then 0 for `a`, and 4 for `b`.  Throwing all caution to the wind, and completely abandoning the realm of managed memory, we *could* do:

```
let changeB pointer newB =
    let bPtr =
        NativePtr.toNativeInt pointer
        |> (+) 4n
        |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt<byte>
    NativePtr.write bPtr newB
```

or even:

```
let changeMember pointer offset (value : 'T) =
    let pointer' =
        NativePtr.toNativeInt pointer
        |> (+) (nativeint offset)
        |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt<'T>
    NativePtr.write pointer' value
```

---

I leave it an open question as to what the *best* method of dealing with these situations is, if they must be dealt with at all.  I am inclined to go with the first, clearest method at the expense of additional memory use.  The last, arbitrary offset method is to be avoided at all costs - if you must deal with adding raw offsets, it is much much better to wrap them in a more easily verifiable function like the second method, so the caller need not calculate the offset itself.